# Can existing .net application be converted to MonoDroid?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can existing .net application(in C#) be converted to MonoDroid? or

Can we port an existing .NET web app to Android using MonoDroid?

Answer (score 1):

MonoDroid is intended to allow you to develop applications in C# as opposed to Java; not as a means to drop an existing application into place.

You asked about a web app, but I'm assuming you mean an ASP.NET web app, which wouldn't map to the Android API, and couldn't simply be copied over. Even taking your HTML and dropping it into something like [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) would still require a lot of JS tweaking to make it work.

I have a feeling you're looking at a re-write. Maybe if you can provide more details (is this an ASP.NET app, etc.), I could give a better answer.

Comment: Gregory, Thanks for your immediate response. Yes It is an asp.net web app.

Comment: No problem. Although it wouldn't be _impossible_ to migrate the logic from an ASP.NET web app to an Android app, the user experience is much different. As an Android user, if an app mirrors the mobile/full web version of a site, I uninstall it and create a shortcut. I think the only real benefit you would see from MonoDroid would be the familiar C# syntax, everything else would be a do-over.

Comment: Is there any other alternative?

Comment: If you're looking for rapid development, the three products I know of are [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/), [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/home/) (which may be best for your situation), and [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html).

Comment: Does PhoneGap support .net(C#) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If C# is a requirement, I believe MonoDroid is your only option ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes no problem. But it wouldn't be an automatic process, nor a particularly simple one. All the UI elements, persistence stuff and so on (the platform specific parts of your application) will need to be redone. Depending on your app, and how it is written, this may be a major part, or a relatively small one. The more corners that were cut originally, the more it will cost to port over.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tom's answer, I would say it has some limitations([link 1](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/142098-what-net-features-does-mono-for-android-support) and [link 2](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations)) . I blogged some other interesting moments [here](http://www.yumasoft.com/node/122).

[Here](http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/tweet-search-one-code-three-mobile-platforms-wp7-monodroid-monotouch/) is a good example of cross-platform mobile application (monoDroid, monoTouch, WP7).